# Best practice for SEO tag / category pages in Umbraco 7+

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7, umbraco-blog

I've tried all the popular blog packages in Umbraco.

People talk alot about articulate, and it's certainly very comforting that one of the core developers are behind this package, BUT...

I just have 1 problem with it - it seems so be somewhat "hardcoded".. By that I mean, doesn't integrate that well into the Umbraco backoffice - at least it seems to me. The "themes" articualte introduces (while a great idea) does not show up in the templates dropdown nor are they stored in the templates table inside Umbraco. So if you want to change templates, you'd have to get your hands "dirty", which defeats the purpose of a CMS like Umbraco, and most clients are not willing to invest time in. :p

Some other blog packages using the built-in Umbraco datatype seems to add the querystring in the url to just filter the posts based on the tag. For SEO reasons I think a url like domain.com/category_slug would be preferred over eg on the official Umbraco blog: `http://umbraco.com/follow-us?filterby=CodeGarden`- wouldn't `http://umbraco.com/category/codegarden` seem like the more SEO friendly option of the two?

Ublogsy seems to go down that route of a traditional category document type, a category template, and instead of using the built-in Umbraco tags datatype, you use the contentpicker to assign the categories.

What confuses me are all those different methods of creating categorization and tags for blog purposes in Umbraco.

From the short experience I currently have with Umbraco, I have already fallen in love with it as a CMS. I'm a former WordPress programmer which has converted to Umbraco, but if the site needs a full featured blog, is Umbraco really geared and suited towards this task? I mean... the community does not seem to have 1 standardized seo friendly way of categorizing and tagging different entities, right?

I was really hoping the Blog 4 Umbraco package would be maintained, since it was created by the founders of Umbraco, but it seems like it isn't compatibele with the breaking changes in the latest versions- a lot of packages seems to have been discontinued and Articulate's approach I'm not entirely convinced about either - mainly due to the themes not integrating correctly with the umbraco database and ui.

What is the most "correct" way to build tags and categories in Umbraco, with dedicated seo archives pages instead of simple filters as query parameters in the url, like we get with the tags datatype?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a document type for your tags, and then a content node for each tag.

That way you can add meta data and optionaly some bodytext.

Then add a content picker multiple for your blog document type so you can pick the tags.

Then in the tag template you can query for the blogs containing the specific tag.